# Draw WICBitmap to window?

Tags: c++, image, mfc, bitmap, wic

I have a `WICBitmap` that contains an image in my MFC program.  Is there any way to draw this bitmap onto a device context?

```
void DrawBitmap(IWICBitmapSource source, HDC targetDC, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy)
{
   //source: The Bitmap to draw
   //TargetDC: The HDC to draw onto (e.g. a printer or screen DC)
   //X,Y: The location on the DC to draw the bitmap

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of samples on MSDN that show how to display a WIC bitmap using, for example, GDI, GDI+, Direct2D etc.

- MSDN: [Image Decoding Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *([archive](https://archive.is/NItdZ))*
- [Introduction to WIC: How to use WIC to load an image, and draw it with GDI?](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2011/10/17/introduction-to-wic-how-to-use-wic-to-load-an-image-and-draw-it-with-gdi/comment-page-1/) *([archive](https://archive.fo/B6IiJ))*

---

Microsoft provides a [WIC Image Viewer Using GDI Sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee720059.aspx) *([GitHub mirror](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wic/wicviewergdi))*

The basic idea is:

- convert **IWicBitmapSource** into a standard Windows **BITMAP** *([`CreateDibSectionFromBitmapSource`](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/wic/wicviewergdi/WicViewerGdi.cpp#L354))*
- draw using the **BITMAP** using your standard tools

Comment: Can you link to any samples on MSDN that show to display a WIC bitmap using GDI or GDI+? Or, better yet, post the code? (the link you gave seems stale - has no code)

Comment: @IanBoyd Yes, sorry, although that link works ok, MSDN has removed those examples! There are others available though- a quick Google [found this blog](http://www.nuonsoft.com/blog/2011/10/17/introduction-to-wic-how-to-use-wic-to-load-an-image-and-draw-it-with-gdi/comment-page-1/), which shows how to render a WIC bitmap using GDI. Although I *could* copy/paste the author's code in my answer, I'm not sure that would be entirely ethical, even with suitable attribution. Maybe that link helps?

Answer (score -1):

The file can be edited separately as bmp file, and after you can load WIC object as you can see in [How to Load a Bitmap from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).